# How do I duplicate constraints from one existing table to another existing table with an identical structure?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, constraint

I'm using PostgreSQL. I have two tables, `table_a` and `table_b`. `table_b` is a structural copy of `table_a` but it was created without the constraints of `table_a`. At a later date, I want to add the constraints to `table_b`.

All the constraints are regular foreign keys to the primary key of `table_a` and for the purposes of this question, we can assume that the data are the same in both tables, but I still don't want to drop and recreate `table_b`; I want to add the constraints independent of table creation.

Is there a generic way of doing this without having to be provided details of the tables' structure or the specific constraints of `table_a`?

Comment: Cannot run `ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT...`?

Comment: There are somewhere on the order of 30 constraints, and I'm hoping for a way to do this agnostically, without regard to what the actual constraints are, so I can easily do it with another set of similarly paired tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table_m
> (
>     id int primary key,
>     f1 int not null,
>     f2 int not null,
>     f3 int not null unique,
>     unique (f1, f2)
> );
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table_a
> (
>     id int primary key,
>     f1 int not null,
>     f2 int not null,
>     f3 int not null,
>     constraint fk_f1_f2 foreign key (f1,f2) references table_m (f1,f2),
>     constraint fk_f3    foreign key (f3)    references table_m (f3)
> );
>
> CREATE TABLE table_b
> (
>     id int primary key,
>     f1 int not null,
>     f2 int not null,
>     f3 int not null
> )
> ```

You can use `information_schema` view to get information about FOREIGN KEYS in this way:

> ```
> SELECT   tc.constraint_name, 
>          tc.table_name, 
>          ccu.table_name AS foreign_table_name,
>          string_agg(distinct kcu.column_name, ',') AS column_name,
>          string_agg(distinct ccu.column_name, ',') AS foreign_column_name 
> FROM     information_schema.table_constraints AS tc 
> JOIN     information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu
> ON       tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name
> JOIN     information_schema.constraint_column_usage AS ccu
> ON       ccu.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name
> WHERE    constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY' 
> AND      tc.table_name='table_a'
> GROUP BY tc.constraint_name, tc.table_name, ccu.table_name;
> ```
>
> ```
> constraint_name | table_name | foreign_table_name | column_name | foreign_column_name
> :-------------- | :--------- | :----------------- | :---------- | :------------------
> fk_f1_f2        | table_a    | table_m            | f1,f2       | f1,f2              
> fk_f3           | table_a    | table_m            | f3          | f3
> ```

You can dynamically build SQL statements to add FOREIGN KEYS.

Copy&Paste and EXECUTE or use a function like this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29617481/3270427) to execute.

> ```
> SELECT   format('ALTER TABLE table_b ADD CONSTRAINT %s FOREIGN KEY (%s) REFERENCES table_m(%s);',
>                  tc.constraint_name, 
>                  string_agg(distinct kcu.column_name, ','),
>                  string_agg(distinct ccu.column_name, ','))
> FROM     information_schema.table_constraints AS tc 
> JOIN     information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu
> ON       tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name
> JOIN     information_schema.constraint_column_usage AS ccu
> ON       ccu.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name
> WHERE    constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY' 
> AND      tc.table_name='table_a'
> GROUP BY tc.constraint_name, tc.table_name, ccu.table_name;
> ```
>
> ```
> | format                                                                                     |
> | :----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | ALTER TABLE table_b ADD CONSTRAINT fk_f1_f2 FOREIGN KEY (f1,f2) REFERENCES table_m(f1,f2); |
> | ALTER TABLE table_b ADD CONSTRAINT fk_f3 FOREIGN KEY (f3) REFERENCES table_m(f3);          |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=7a0c69b6c4f377b473423eef5fd79cc6)*

Answer (score 0):

Use pg_dump with the "-s" (schema only) and "-t" (which table) options.  That should give you a script in which you can alter the name of the table.